# How to obfuscate an ASP.Net MVC3 Project using Dotfuscator?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, obfuscation, deobfuscation, dotfuscator

I have a project to obfuscate.
Its having layers separated such as Services,Data,Web,Models etc..
I am using nHibernate ORM also. 
Also like to know how to handle ajax also during obfustication.
I prefer to use dotfuscator. Can any one help me in showing how to do it?

Comment: Obfuscating a website is a very unusual scenario.  Are you sure you need to do that or that it is even reasonable?  Also, a public API between components is a public API.  You can make the method names gibberish (probably by hand, honestly), but people can still call into the public API.  If I were you, I would push back pretty hard on the business scenario.  Any business model dependent on this kind of technical solution is probably too weak to make it in the real world.  Also, getting rid of the layered components would massively simply the problem, those are unnecessary at runtime.

Comment: Still cannot resolve the issue. The Business guys are making a point they should be able to obfuscate the dll.